# Cloudflare blocks our "between subdomains" url rewrites with a 403 due to X-ORIGINAL-URL header(CVE-2018-14773)

Tags: azure, rewrite, cloudflare, arr

**Question:** How to remove the **X-ORIGINAL-URL** header in Azure ARR?

Cloudflare blocks our "between subdomains" url rewrites with a 403 due to X-ORIGINAL-URL header (CVE-2018-14773).

We are using an applicationHost.xdt file and rewrite rules in web.config.

**The rule is:**

```
<rule name="Rule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(ab|cd|ef|gh)/(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add matchType="Pattern" input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^sub\.domain\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <serverVariables>
        <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
    </serverVariables>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://sub.{R:1}.domain.com/{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

**applicationHost.xdt:**

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <system.webServer>
        <proxy xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" enabled="true" preserveHostHeader="false" reverseRewriteHostInResponseHeaders="false" />
    </system.webServer>
    <location path="%XDT_SITENAME%" xdt:Locator="Match(path)">
        <system.webServer xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
            <httpProtocol xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
                <customHeaders xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
                     <add xdt:Transform="Remove" /> 
                </customHeaders>
            </httpProtocol>
            
            <rewrite xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
                <allowedServerVariables xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" >
                    <add name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
                    <add name="HTTP_HOST" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
                    <add name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
                    <add name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
                </allowedServerVariables>
            </rewrite>
        </system.webServer>            
    </location>
</configuration>
```

**Cloudflare log (part):**

```
{
    "key": "rule_message",
    "value": "Drupal, Wordpress - Anomaly:Header:X-Original-Url, Anomaly:Header:X-Rewrite-Url - CVE:CVE-2018-14773"
},
```